# jQuery ajax works on local but not on server

Tags: jquery, ajax

I m actually put of my min with this code ....

```
$.ajax({
                'url'               : site_root + '/ajax.php',
                'type'          : 'POST',
                'data'          : 'function=check_user_login_name&user_login=' + user_login,
                beforeSend  : function()
                {
                    $('#check_result_span').html('Checking ...');
                },
                success         : function(data)
                {
                    if(data != 1)
                    {
                        $('#check_result_span').addClass('green').html('Available!');
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $('#check_result_span').addClass('red').html('Already taken!');
                    }
                }
            });
```

This works fine on local machine, but not on server ...

the server page link is http://onlyfreelancer.com/signup.php

Please click on the "Check availability" link, nothing happens on server but on local it shows if the user login name is still available or not

Any help plz?

Comment: I get an alert - 'status: success'?

Comment: thats what i see, just removed the alert(). whats worse is that i see no entry in firebug console when i click on that link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When that link is clicked, the resulting request is for:

```
http://www.onlyfreelancer.com/ajax.php
```

but (at least in my Safari debugger), the origin is seen as

```
http://onlyfreelancer.com
```

Perhaps this is a "same origin policy" issue. Can you set up your code to request ajax.php from onlyfreelancer.com (no www)?

Comment: actually http://www.onlyfreelancer.com/ajax.php is the link where the post is being made. i have a var site_root which holds "http://www.onlyfreelancer.com"

Comment: Yes -- so `site_root` = `http://www.onlyfreelancer.com`, thus your ajax call URL is `http://www.onlyfreelancer.com/ajax.php`. But you're loading it from the page `http://onlyfreelancer.com/signup.php`. No www. The same origin policy wants to see the same URL in the calling page and the page requested via ajax.

Comment: Yep! Thats it. Sorry, Ken i had a misconception about the same origin policy. i thought ajax calls just need to be done to same domain and didn't count for subdomains. Many thanks :)